# Will MS Still Force Windows 10 Upgrade After Free Period Ends

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-10

Since after July 29, 2016 the Windows 10 upgrade is no longer going to be free, does anyone know if these upgrades will still be 'forced' and what the consequences of not paying for the upgrade will be?

Comment: we can't answer this. MS has not provided any information what happens

Answer (score 2):

The upgrade even free is not forced.

It will never be forced.

The consequence of not upgrading will be like any other OS upgrade:

- Some day you will not receive any more support. (safe)
- Some time after that you will not receive any standard updates. (unsafe)
- Some time after that you will not receive even security updates. (dangerous!)

Comment: Maybe not forced but many report W10 installation after reboot, without consent.

Comment: this answer is crap. Win7 gets updates till 2020 and 8.1 till 2023.

Comment: @ Moab Those who report that are the same people who don't read or even check what they're installing when they use Windows Update.

Comment: @magicandre1981 How is my answer crap? What you state about updates is completely congruent with my answer.

Comment: no, you posted the opposite . Your answer says upgrade to win10 or you don't get updates any longer.

Comment: I answered his question "does anyone know if these upgrades will still be 'forced'", by stating the fact that the upgrade has never been forced (despite some people's misunderstandings). So the premise of his second question "and what the consequences of not paying for the upgrade will be?", isn't valid in the first place. I still don't see the crap in it. If I'm interpreting things incorrectly, please correct me constructively so we can provide better content for SU.